# How to replace "Floating point exception" error with an error of my own

Tags: c, divide-by-zero

I have an assignment from my school in which I'd enter 2 numbers which are 5 and 0 and divide it and a display result showing `"Result is undefined - division by 0 is encountered"`.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num, num2, sum, diff, pro, quo;
    int operation;
    
    printf("Enter 1st num: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("Enter 2nd num: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);
    printf("Choose Operation: ");
    printf("\n [1] Addition \n [2] Subtraction \n [3] Multiplication \n [4] Divison \n");
    printf("Choice: ");
    scanf("%d", &operation);
    
    sum = num + num2;
    diff = num - num2;
    pro = num * num2;
    quo = num / num2;
    
    switch(operation)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("Result of adding %d and %d is %d", num, num2, sum);
        break;

    case 2:
        printf("%d - %d = %d", num, num2, diff);
        break;

    case 3:
        printf("%d * %d = %d", num, num2, pro);
        break;

    case 4:
        switch(operation)
        {
        case 4:
            printf("%d / %d = %d", num, num2, quo);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Result is undefined - division by 0 is encountered");
        }
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of waiting for a car to crash into a wall and then see what happened, you normally ensure that this will not happen. You can do this here as well: Simply check if you are going to do division by zereo and in that case just don't do it. Print the error instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That message is probably thrown due to the `SIGFPE` signal being raised. By including `<signal.h>`, you can handle the signal and print your own message. Here's an example.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void handle(int sig)
{
    puts("Result is undefined");
    exit(1);
}

int main(void)
{
    signal(SIGFPE, handle);
    int a = 5 / 0;
}
```

Under normal circumstances, this printed `Floating point exception` for me, but with the signal handler, it prints a custom message and then exits. For me, if I don't exit immediately after printing, it prints my custom message infinitely, so removing the `exit(1)` may not be the best idea. Unfortunately, you cannot be certain if the signal was raised due to a divide-by-0 error, but in your program, it is likely to be the only cause.

Alternatively, you could also just check if the divisor is 0 before you try dividing, in which case you could be certain it would be a divide-by-0 error.

Comment: I did the alternate, I used an if function to check if the divisor is 0 hehe I just thought of that when you pointed that out.. now I feel stupid haha, thank youu

Comment: @Eric no problem ;) I'd also suggest you do the calculations inside the `switch` statement conditions too so that you only have to do the calculations which are necessary, and you would also only have to check for zero if you want to divide.

Answer (score 0):

That error is triggered by the processor because you divide by zero. If you check the input before doing the division, you can display your own error. Then only do the division if the input is not zero, otherwise you will still trigger the error.